# Don't open a HTML link if drag-and-dropped to Emacs

Tags: html, hyperlinks, drag-and-drop

I keep my notes in Markdown. Often I would like to collect various links by drag-and-dropping them from the browser.

However, Emacs opens them instead. I know that this is probably what most people want, but is there any way to disable this, so Emacs will not open a link but just insert it as a text

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the Drag and Drop behavior using the variable `dnd-protocol-alist`. The ultimate fallback is inserting the link as text, so this is what you want:

```
(setq dnd-protocol-alist nil)
```

The following is the default value, you can also remove `http` only

```
(("^file:///" . dnd-open-local-file)
 ("^file://" . dnd-open-file)
 ("^file:" . dnd-open-local-file)
 ("^\\(https?\\|ftp\\|file\\|nfs\\)://" . dnd-open-file))
```

By the way, you can do interesting thing with `dnd-protocol-alist`, such as, drag a html url into a markdown buffer and insert it as markdown link automatically. One existing cool use of it is Dired, when you drag a file into a dired buffer, the file will be copy&paste into that directory.

Comment: Thank you, both solutions worked. The first one to switch off brutally ;-) and the second one with the removal of http. Thanks!